# Swift3 Storekit - Cast string array to Set<ProductIdentifier>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to implement storekit in app purchases. The following hardcoded value works just fine:

My Globals Struct:

```
static var productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = ["com.app.myIAP"]
static var store = IAPHelper(productIds: Globals.productIdentifiers)
```

In my function:

```
Globals.store = IAPHelper(productIds: productIdentifiers)
```

But when I try to create the identifiers dynamically, I get an error:

```
var strIdentifiers = [String]()
for subscription in subscriptions {
    strIdentifiers.append(subscription["id"] as! String)
}
let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = strIdentifiers
Globals.store = IAPHelper(productIds: productIdentifiers)
Globals.store.requestProducts{success, products in
    if success {
        .......
    }
}
```

I get this Error:

```
Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'Set<ProductIdentifier>' (aka 'Set<String>')
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: How is `subscriptions` defined?

Comment: let subscriptions = pages["subscriptions"] as! [NSDictionary]

Answer (score 1):

`subscription["id"]` returns an `Array` of type `[ProductIdentifier]`.

You can not cast an array to a type `as! ProductIdentifier`.

Either:

Change the cast to  `as! [ProductIdentifier]`

or

Check the place where you set `subscription["id"]`. Maybe you set an array accidentally.

I assume the later, as an "id" should probably be an `ProductIdentifier`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manipulate as a Set:

```
for subscription in subscriptions {
    Globals.productIdentifiers.insert(subscription["id"] as! String)
}
Globals.products = []
Globals.store = IAPHelper(productIds: Globals.productIdentifiers)
Globals.store.requestProducts{success, products in
    if success {
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of answering your own question, prefer to update the question.